# Auto-mount USB drive when plugged in on Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, usb, mount, alpine-linux

I know that Alpine Linux doesn't enable the auto-mounting of USB drives when they are plugged in but I have an application where I would like this to work without the user needing to mount the drive to use it.

I have added the drive to the /etc/fstab file and it works to auto-mount where I want it, but only on boot of the machine. If I plug in the drive after the system is already booted, it will not invoke the fstab file and mount the drive.

My two initial thoughts are:

1. Is it possible to adjust the system to invoke the fstab file when the USB drive is plugged in? I would prefer it to be only if this device is identified but it could be for any USB device, if required.
2. Is there a way to invoke a bash script upon this drive getting plugged in that performs the mount action automatically?

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Auto Mounting USB drives has not been supported for some years. Linux is not any different on my machines (Ubuntu and Kali) .

Comment: I guess I was figuring that the same auto-mount mechanisms that GUI-based installs employ could be made to happen in the Alpine environment, but as @u1686_grawity stated, this is done a different way in GUI environments. I may see about using `udev` simply for the mount command.

Answer (score 0):

The general method of running short commands on device connection is `udev`. An udev rule can use `RUN+=` to run a command; on non-systemd distributions this can be used to call `mount`.<sup>1</sup>

Graphical desktop environments will often have their own auto-mount features, often based on udisks2.

The traditional method of mounting transient filesystems is `autofs`, which mounts things *when accessed* rather than when plugged in. Autofs comes with examples for CDs and floppy disks, but can be adapted for any other fstab entry.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that udev rule processing is paused while the command runs. This has several implications: 1) You can't use rules to do things that rely on the rule processing being finished; e.g. `mount` is fine, but `xprop` will just not work. 2) You can't run long-running commands directly; daemons must background (daemonize).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I'm going to look into simply mounting with the udev rule. The `umount` will still need to be manual, regardless, so maybe this isn't worthwhile but I'll look into it.